# Max Lyapunov Exponent of a Double Pendulum

Tags: computational-physics, simulations, chaos-theory

Using Euler's method I got this graph. I used separation between angles $10^{-10}$, $\Delta t$ of integration 0.0001s and max time 100s. The initial angles are the same ($\theta_1=\theta_2$).

I expected the values to be a lot higher at high initial energy positions. Have I made any mistakes?
[image: test]

Comment: What is being plotted here?

Comment: Specifically, what's on the x-axis?

Comment: What kind of double pendulum is this? One rigid pendulum hanging from the end of another? Real pendulum, or point masses with zero mass rods?

Comment: Equivalently, what is the Lagrangian or Hamiltonian you're using to get your equations of motion?

Comment: @KyleKanos The axis labels are missing, but what's being plotted in described in the caption: Lyapunov exponent as a function of initial angle (both are the same according to the question body).

Comment: @SeanE.Lake I obtained equations of motion using Lagrangian, I was using rigid bodies, constant rod length, point mass of bob and rods without mass, no friction etc. so idealised mathematical model.

Comment: And yes, sorry for the mediocre description of graph. Made it in a rush.

Comment: By Euler method you mean the integration scheme? It would actually be important to now how do you compute the LE, since there're different ways of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remember that, for an angle, $\pi\approx 6.28\approx 0$, i.e., it's a periodic variable, so your plot does show higher values for higher angles.

As for the values themselves, you should simulate for longer times, but, without further details (such as initial velocities and parameter values) they seem like they could be going in the right direction. You can check the questions [Why is my Lyapunov exponent similar for single and double pendulum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/192465/75633), and [Do the Lyapunov exponents depend on integrals of motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/296175/75633) for common mistakes to avoid and tips on the calculation. And, for comparison, a plot similar to yours can be found [here](http://psi.nbi.dk/@psi/wiki/The%20Double%20Pendulum/files/projekt_2013-14_RON_EH_BTN.pdf), and it's probably worth it checking [this](https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m53f09/public_html/proj/Roja_writeup.pdf).

Main references for you could be the papers [A numerical analysis of chaos in the double pendulum](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.chaos.2005.08.032) ([e-print](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01389907/)), [Double pendulum: An experiment in chaos](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.17335) ([e-print](https://physics.csuchico.edu/ayars/427/handouts/AJP001038.pdf)), and [Chaos in a double pendulum](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.16860) ([e-print](http://materias.df.uba.ar/mcaa2017c2/files/2017/08/AJPDoublePendulum2.pdf)). Notice that the last two give $\lambda_+\in [3, 8]$, so your current values might indeed be too low.

Comment: I will try increasing runtime of simulation. I made this post because I am scared that calling the behaviour chaotic with such low lyapunov exponent might be seen as a critical mistake. P.S. I meant the lyapunov exponent at higher initial energy positions. I know that after $\pi$ the values are mirrored.

Comment: @MateuszBelka I took a second look and your values do look too low. I added new relevant references to the answer.